# Reducing the amount of attributes returned

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have a filter in one of my user importers, which looks like:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=somegroup,OU=some,OU=thing,DC=org,DC=company,DC=com))
```

The filter works like expected, but due to the fact that each user has tons of attributes I'm looking for a method on how to cut down the output a little bit. I.e. fields I need are sAMAaccountName, authorizedPassword and about 5 other fields.

Is there a way on how to cut the output down, that only those fields (or attributes?) are shown, but for all users in that group. Haven been looking around for a while but did not find any proper hint.

Many thanks in advance, regards, Thomas

Comment: You cannot say which attributes to return in the LDAP filter string. There generally is a separate way to do this, which is dependent on the LDAP client software/library you are using. Show your code and the name & version of the software/library.

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to me to show you the code used, it is a third party software where I do not have access to the source. :(

Comment: Without knowing which software or tool you're using (name and version are sufficient), it's impossible to point you into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the returned attributes for the searchRequest as an example similar to:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h <domain> -b "OU=thing,DC=org,DC=company,DC=com)" -s sub "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=somegroup,OU=some,OU=thing,DC=org,DC=company,DC=com))" samaccountName
```

You can "Google/Bing" for ldapsearch examples or read https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch

Since you did not mention how the search was being done, kin of hard to offer more information.

-jim

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try. Generally it's a java application running in a Apache Tomcat, so I have to try this if the built in client is capable to take such options. Many thanks!